# Reuse loopback model for client side validation in backbone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

I would like to use *StrongLoop Loopback* as a *Node.js* backend API for a *backbone.js* app.

Is there a way to define models attributes and methods (for example, for validation) that can be used both on the client side, in the backbone model, and on the server, in *Loopback* models definitions ? (*Dont Repeat Yourself* philosophy)

[Loopback uses model definitions to initialize objects](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Creating+a+LoopBack+application#CreatingaLoopBackapplication-Creatingmodels)

Maybe I can extend `Backbone.Model` to be able to load the *Loopback* model definition syntax ?

Do you think it's a good idea / easy task ?

Answer (score 2):

disclosure: I do front-end work for StrongLoop.

It is a good idea since the model definitions are stored as simple json.  You can also use the  API explorer output to pick up the url path properties as well.

We are just wrapping up a similar thing for AngularJS to auto-gen a model factory you can drop into your client modules and it's pretty slick so hopefully a Backbone version won't be too far behind.

Comment: That would be DEFINITELY useful ! I can't wait to see the "coming soon JS SDK" advertised in the docs, do you know how far the release is from now ?

Comment: I'll try to write a complete answer here with the `Backbone.Model` class extension doing the job, in a few weeks.

Comment: Hi, I'm going to do `Backbone.Model` extension too. Do you have any positive results? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Pandaiolo have you had time to write up a complete answer yet?

Comment: Not yet, I am waiting for [this full stack example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-full-stack) to be more complete. However, I switched to Angular as there is a very convenient resource object generator available for Loopback.

Comment: This would be very valuable, I think. +1